# Very slow wifi on Ubuntu 15.10 and Macbook Pro

Tags: networking, java, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time yesterday. I don't use the terminal very often so I have some issues installing programs.

First of all : could you please help to speed up my wifi ? I'm using a mid-2012 MacBook Pro. It's better than yesterday because I didn't have wifi at all and I did a command on terminal (b43 something) and now I have wifi. But it's very slow. It seems that my Wifi controller was made by broadcom

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16a3] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16b4]
03:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00ef]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: `03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16a3] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16b4]
03:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00ef]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
`

Comment: I've edited the question, but he has to accept it. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A worng driver is installed. It can be fixed by running:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: Thanks! Will test it. Have you been able to make the trackpad work in a better way? Is kind of annoying the tap so sensible...

Comment: Thannk you for your answer but when I type sudo modprobe -r wl it says "modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found."

Comment: It is OK, the previous command did that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I might have found an answer thanks to Pilot6.

When you go to the system settings, there is "Software & Updates". Here you have to go to 'Additional drivers' and select the one you want.

For me it works, now wifi is really faster, but not as fast as on OS X.